# Combine variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I have 2 variables which contain values. Here are the variables:

```
$a = "1a, 2a, 3a, 3a_oth, 4a, 4a_oth";
$b = "1, 1, 8, Port, 10, UNIX";
```

How can I combine both variables to get this?

```
$c = array('1a'=>'1', '2a'=>'1', '3a'=>'8', '3a_oth'=>'Port', '4a'=>'10', '4a_oth'=>'UNIX');
```

Comment: $a and $b are strings like: `$a = '1a, 2a, 3a, 3a_oth, 4a, 4a_oth,';`

Comment: That's not valid code, however you look at it. Can you please provide actual samples or clear up your question? Are you talking about *combining arrays*? (hint hint, search for those keywords!)

Comment: Looks like you have arrays there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have two string and want a third string, not an associative array:

```
$a = '1a, 2a, 3a, 3a_oth, 4a, 4a_oth';
$b = '1, 1, 8, Port, 10, UNIX';

function combine($a,$b){
    $c='';
    $aa = preg_split('/, /',$a);
    $bb = preg_split('/, /',$b);
    if(count($aa)!=count($bb))return false;
    for($i=0;$i<count($aa);$i++){
        $c.=$aa[$i].'='.$bb[$i];
        if($i!=count($aa)-1)$c.=', ';
    }
    return $c;
}
echo combine($a,$b); // returns 1a=1, 2a=1, 3a=8, 3a_oth=Port, 4a=10, 4a_oth=UNIX
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) function.

You could do something like this, assuming `$a` and `$b` are comma-delimited strings and not arrays. If they're already arrays, you can skip the `explode` step and just pass them directly to `array_combine`.

```
$a = "1a, 2a, 3a, 3a_oth, 4a, 4a_oth";
$b = "1, 1, 8, Port, 10, UNIX";

$c = array_combine( explode(",", $a), explode(",",$b) );
```

The [`explode`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function turns the comma-delimited strings into arrays.

Then the array based on `$a` is used for the new array's keys while the array based on `$b` is used for the values.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the above variables are arrays, use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

If `$a` and `$b` are comma-delimited strings, then use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) first.

```
$a = explode("," $a); // only if $a is a string
$b = explode("," $b); // only if $b is a string

$a = array('1a', '2a', '3a', '3a_oth', '4a', '4a_oth'); // keys
$b = array('1', '1', '8', 'Port', '10', 'UNIX');        // values

$c = array_combine($a, $b); 
// outputs array('1a' => '1', '2a' => '1', '3a' => '8' ... )
```